# Irrational equation system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals, substitution

I need to solve an equation system :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{7x+y}+\sqrt{x+y}&=&6\\
\sqrt{x+y}+x-y&=&2
\end{eqnarray*}
I know that $x=2, y=2$ is the right solution I don't see the way to get there, and I am a bit lazy to do all the calculations with the squares..is there any other way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{x+y}=t$. Thus, $t\geq0$, $$t+t^2-2y=2,$$ which gives
$$y=\frac{t^2+t-2}{2}$$ and we obtain:
$$\sqrt{7t^2-3(t^2+t-2)}+t=6$$ or
$$4t^2-3t+6=(6-t)^2,$$ where $0\leq t\leq6$, which gives $t=2$, $y=2$ and $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

solving your second equation for $$\sqrt{x+y}$$ and plugging this in the first equation we get
$$\sqrt{7x+y}+2-x+y=6$$ isolate the square root and square the equation
and you will get $$-16-x-x^2+9y+2xy-y^2=0$$ solve this for $x$ or $y$
we get $$x=2,y=2$$, check it!

Comment: yes you have right i have changed a plus sign into minus sign,have a nice evening Michael

Answer (score 0):

When you have two radicals, an often convenient technique is to consider
$$
(\sqrt{7x+y}+\sqrt{x+y})(\sqrt{7x+y}-\sqrt{x+y})=6(\sqrt{7x+y}-\sqrt{x+y})
$$
that easily yields
$$
\sqrt{7x+y}-\sqrt{x+y}=x
$$
Subtracting this from the first equation, we get
$$
2\sqrt{x+y}=6-x\tag{*}
$$
and substituting in the second equation we obtain
$$
6-x+2x-2y=4
$$
or $x=2y-2$. Now, substituting in (*),
$$
\sqrt{3y-2}=4-y
$$
We can square, getting
$$
3y-2=16-8y+y^2\qquad y^2-11y+18=0
$$
The roots are $y=2$ and $y=9$, but the second would make $4-y<0$, so it should be discarded.